# Drools upgrade: Stream Closed Exception

Tags: java, spring, drools

I am trying to upgrade drools from 7.33.0 to 7.60.0. On upgrading I am seeing the following exception -

`Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer]: Factory method 'kieContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`

My code is something like this -

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileEntry.getPath());
kfs.write("src/main/resources/" + fileEntry.getName(), kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource(fis));
fis.close();

KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();  --> Line where exception is thrown
```

How can I get rid of this exception?

Comment: Stream Closed indicates a problem with the FileInputStream, not anything Drools related.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the "fis.close();" line in your code.